# Slide анимация + overflow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animation

Нужно реализовать: когда кликаем на .dev-site-opener - .dev-site-text получает высоту такую же как у его ребенка .dev-site-text > p. И в итоге мы получаем анимацию где плавноп оказывается текст. Но нужно сделать так чтобы когда один блок открыт и мы нажимаем на другой тот что открыт закрывается, а открывается тот на который мы нажали.

```js
$('.dev-site-opener').click(function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  var text = $(this).parent().find('.dev-site-text');
  if (!_this.hasClass('active-1')) {
    text.height(1);
    _this.addClass('active-1');
  } else {
    text.height(text.find('p').height());
    _this.removeClass('active-1');
  }
});
```

```css
.slider-dev-site-wrap {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.slide-dev-site-cont {
  margin: 80px auto;
  width: 1120px;
}

.slide-dev-site-cont .left-dev-site {
  float: left;
  width: 538px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-dev-site-cont .right-dev-site {
  float: left;
  width: 538px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-dev-site-title {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font: 500 27px/29px 'Proxima Nova', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
  padding: 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.right-dev-site-title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  background: #f9da00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 3px;
}

.dev-site-list {
  text-align: left;
}

.dev-site-list li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dev-site-list .dev-site-opener {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #282828;
}

.dev-site-list .dev-site-opener:before {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #000;
  left: -30px;
  top: 2px;
}

.dev-site-list .active-1:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dev-site-list .dev-site-text {
  padding-left: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-dev-site-body">
  <ul class="dev-site-list">
    <li>
      <div class="dev-site-opener">Проектирование. Разработка уникального и эксклюзивного дизайна</div>
      <div class="dev-site-text">
        <p>
          Проектирование интерфейса будущего сайта. Продумывание юзабилити. Совокупность графических элементов, шрифтов, цветов, индивидуальных тематических иконок, реализованных на сайте.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dev-site-opener">Проектирование2. Разработка уникального и эксклюзивного дизайна</div>
      <div class="dev-site-text">
        <p>
          Проектирование интерфейса будущего сайта2. Продумывание юзабилити. Совокупность графических элементов, шрифтов, цветов, индивидуальных тематических иконок, реализованных на сайте.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

добрый день, т.к. подключен jquery вот решения для анимации методами jquery

```js
$('.dev-site-opener').click(function() {
  var _this = $(this);

 _this.next('.dev-site-text').slideToggle();
 _this.parent('li').siblings().find('.dev-site-text').slideUp();
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider-dev-site-wrap {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.slide-dev-site-cont {
  margin: 80px auto;
  width: 1120px;
}

.slide-dev-site-cont .left-dev-site {
  float: left;
  width: 538px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-dev-site-cont .right-dev-site {
  float: left;
  width: 538px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-dev-site-title {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font: 500 27px/29px 'Proxima Nova', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
  padding: 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.right-dev-site-title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  background: #f9da00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 3px;
}

.dev-site-list {
  text-align: left;
}

.dev-site-list li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dev-site-list .dev-site-opener {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #282828;
}

.dev-site-list .dev-site-opener:before {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #000;
  left: -30px;
  top: 2px;
}

.dev-site-list .active-1:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dev-site-list .dev-site-text {
  padding-left: 40px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 14px;
  display:none;
  width:100%;
}
p {
  margin:0;
 padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right-dev-site-body">
  <ul class="dev-site-list">
    <li>
      <div class="dev-site-opener">Проектирование. Разработка уникального и эксклюзивного дизайна</div>
      <div class="dev-site-text">
        <p>
          Проектирование интерфейса будущего сайта. Продумывание юзабилити. Совокупность графических элементов, шрифтов, цветов, индивидуальных тематических иконок, реализованных на сайте.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dev-site-opener">Проектирование2. Разработка уникального и эксклюзивного дизайна</div>
      <div class="dev-site-text">
        <p>
          Проектирование интерфейса будущего сайта2. Продумывание юзабилити. Совокупность графических элементов, шрифтов, цветов, индивидуальных тематических иконок, реализованных на сайте.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание что для корректной работы нужно указать ширину у скрываемого элемента не должно быть внешних отступов (используйте паддинг вместо марджин)
 P.S. Если хотите можете реализовать анимации на css - тогда манипулируйте высотой "max-height". Если в проекте подключен бутстрап, то в нем уже есть аккордеон.

Comment: вот как надо было все таки додумал логику, может кому и пригодится

Comment: обычно все задачи решаются, после того как разбираешь одну сложную задачу на несколько простых. Можно составить себе список и решать каждую задачу отдельно и последовательно

Answer (score 0):

все таки додумал логику, может кому и пригодится

```js
$('.dev-site-opener').click(function(){
    var _this = $(this),
        text = $(this).parent().find('.dev-site-text');
    if(_this.hasClass('active-1')){
        _this.removeClass('active-1');
        text.height(1);
    }
    else{
        $('.dev-site-opener').removeClass('active-1');
        $('.dev-site-text').height(1);
        text.height(text.find('p').height() +20);
        _this.addClass('active-1');
    }
});
```